# How to parse XML with a qualified xmlns:lang attribute using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, xml-namespaces

I have to parse an XML file and to do this I am using the JAXB library.

Inside the file there is an `xml:lang` attribute that I was able to parse using the namespace *http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace*, but I cannot find the suitable namespace for `xmlns:lang`.
I thought the default value was http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns but it still doesn't work.

Unfortunately I cannot ask to modify the file to use another namespace, do you have any suggestions?

**Example:**
To get `xml:lang`:

```
<ServiceDescription xml:lang="en">eng</ServiceDescription>
```

I use the following code (the namespace is not specified in XML file):

```
@XmlAttribute(name = "lang", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")
private String lang;
```

But I am not able to get `xmlns:lang` from here:

```
<SoftAttribute xmlns:lang="en">eng</SoftAttribute>
```

Comment: can you post an example of the XML? It isn't clear whether we are talking about `xml:lang` (which is the standard means of expressing language) or `xmlns:lang` (which may be a namespace-prefix for some other namespace, or a typeo in your question). Seeing the XML would make it more clear what we are talking about.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question with an example...

Comment: It still is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Are you **trying** to generate the second XML file that has the `xmlns:lang="en"` and don't know how to achieve that, or is that what is being generated when you are trying to declare the `xml:lang="en"`? Or are you trying to read a file like the second example and don't know how to reference that namespace declaration?

Comment: I need to parse an XML file and then save the information in a database. Inside file there are attributes both `xmlns:lang="en"` and `xml:lang="en"` and I am not able to map to java object `xmlns:lang="en"` attribute because don't know how to reference this namespace declaration.